# Perl eval not catching exceptions

Tags: perl, exception

Why doesn't Perl catch this exception?

```
my $fh;
eval { close $fh };
warn('Caught') if &@;
```

with an output of:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at New_test.pl line 30.
```

**UPDATE**: same output without the warn line and `eval { close $fh };` is line 30.

Comment: Please show us *actual code that gives rise to this error*.  Running your snippet in a contemporary perl does not produce the warning you indicate.

Comment: Okay, what the heck... I commented out the code and you're right, Perl does not fail as stated. However, I uncommented the code and now it runs fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is not in **eval**, its on line below, `&@` is wrong sequence, you meant `$@`

UPD: Note that **close** can **die** when you have **strict** on and $fh is undef which i think is not normal case (an algorithm bug).

Comment: False, at least in 5.012 close will die if given an undef, but you are right that &@ is incorrect.

Comment: @EricFossum im trying on Perl 5.14.2 and 5.8.8 `perl -e '$a=undef; close $a;'` is not dying.

Comment: I assume you're running Linux? I couldn't use single quotes, but here's my output. `Z:\>perl -e "use 5.012; my $a; close $a;"
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at -e line 1.

Z:\>perl -e "my $a; close $a;"

Z:\>`

Comment: @EricFossum tested again. Yes it dies(on my freebsd too) when `use strict;` the pragma `use 5.012;` enables strict too. Updated answ.

Comment: Ahh, I wondered if it had something to do with strict. I couldn't figure out why they would make it die in only 5.012 :)

Comment: @EricFossum strange, it dies on my test without "use 5.012", but with "use strict" only.. Perl 5.14.2

Comment: I think that is correct. Maybe there was a communication issue.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you meant `$@` and not `&@`? The latter will be interpreted as a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$@` and not `&@`.
Please refer [this link](http://www.kichwa.com/quik_ref/spec_variables.html) to see what do all special variables Perl has.

`$@` means The Perl syntax error or routine error message from the last eval, do-FILE, or require command. If set, either the compilation failed, or the die function was executed within the code of the eval.

Answer (score 0):

The eval block does catch the exception and prevents it from being fatal.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

This program dies with the expected message when close executes.
For comparison:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;
eval { close $fh; };
print "done\n";
```

This program runs quietly and executes the print statement at the end.